# O "elif" não deixa executar o que é esperado

Tags: python, if

Se fizer `if` cada um sozinho e executar com `else`, o cálculo aparece correto. Mas se usar os dois (`if` e `elif`) não reconhece as diferenças e não exibe os resultados esperados. Só haverá o desconto de R$7,00 se o preço estiver entre o número 23 e a idade digitada.

```
idade = int(input('Qual sua idade? '))
preço = float(input('Informe o valor: '))

#Desconto, deve estar entre o número 23 e a idade do cliente.

desconto = float(7)
if preço >= 23:
    print('Você terá um desconto de: R${:.2f}'.format(desconto))
elif preço <= idade:
    print('Você terá um desconto de: R${:.2f}'.format(desconto))
else:
    print('sem desconto')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leia a descrição do critério que deve ser usado para dar o desconto. Tem um **e** ali, e é isso que deve fazer. Não existem duas condições diferentes, existe apenas uma composta de duas partes, ela tem limites da faixa a ser considerada.

Nunca use dois blocos de comandos para executar exatamente a mesma ação, basta um. Então não faz sentido fazer o `elif` aí, deve criar uma condição composta pelas duas partes do que está descrito que deve ser.

Use um `and` para concatenar as duas partes:

```
idade = int(input('Qual sua idade? '))
preço = float(input('Informe o valor: '))
desconto = 7.0
if preço >= 23 and preço <= idade:
    print('Você terá um desconto de: R${:.2f}'.format(desconto))
else:
    print('sem desconto')
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/4zECcZ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/DoubleConditionpy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/DoubleCondition.py).

Em Python é possível fazer assim também:

```
if 23 <= preço <= idade:
```